# Remove duplicate value based on key value?

Tags: php, arrays

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [feature code] => PPL
            [country code] => ES
            [admin1code] => 51
            [admin2code] => H
            [name] => Zalamea la Real
            [asciiname] => Zalamea la Real
            [id] => 108164
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [feature code] => PPLA3
            [country code] => ES
            [admin1code] => 51
            [admin2code] => H
            [name] => Zalamea la Real
            [asciiname] => Zalamea la Real
            [id] => 108188
        )
```

My array has similar duplicates where **name** value is a duplicate one rest not.

How to unset all duplicate but leave one?

Comment: did you search regarding this? Or tried anything?

Comment: array_unique won't work case only name is same rest is not!

Comment: foreach ($array_adm2_a as $val)
{
 foreach ($array_adm2_a as $vall)
 {
  if($val['asciiname'] == $vall['asciiname'])
  {
  unset($array_adm2_a[$vall]);
  }
  
 }
}
doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 $repeating = [];
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      if(in_array($value['name'], $repeating)) {
          unset($data[$key]['name']);
      }
      else {
          $repeating[] = $value['name'];
       }
 }
```

Comment: GUYS thank yo all array_unique works: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php#116302